# How to find difference between two dates using date_diff() from array

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I need to find the difference between 2 dates from an array. Here is the array:

```
$lists[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user->created_at));
```

Example output of `echo $lists[1];` is `2017-08-01`

I have tried

```
$difftime = $lists[1]->diff($lists[0]);
echo $difftime->format('d');
```

and `echo $lists[1]->diff($lists[0]);`

Both giving me error:

> Call to a member function diff() on string

I have also tried `echo date_diff($lists[1], $lists[0]);`

It's giving error

> date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

I know there are many questions on same issue here, but I could not find a solution that works for me. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference:-[diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

It takes ***DateTimeInterface*** as an parameter and it will called also on a ***DateTimeInterface*** only.

So do like below:-

```
<?php
$lists=array('2017-08-23','2017-08-26');

$datetime1 = new DateTime($lists[0]);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($lists[1]);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/850404

Comment: It works...!!! :)

Comment: @Ahsan glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 5):

Before you can calculate the differences using `DateTimeInterface::diff()`, you need to create instances of `DateTimeInterface` first, for example:

```
$dateOne = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d',
    $lists[0]
);

$dateTwo = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d',
    $lists[1]
);

$difference = $dateTwo->diff($dateOne);
```

Note that `$difference` will be an instance of `DateInterval` - if you need the difference as a string, you need to use `$difference->format()` with the desired format.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: I don't know who's been downvoting you or why, because yours is the more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Sammitch, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi, I am not getting error, but the result is unexpected. $list[0] date is 2017-07-20 and $lists[1] is 2017-08-01. so the result should be 10 days, but I am getting 19. I added this in the end: $difftime = $difference->format('d'); echo $difftime;
out put is 19. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `$difference->format("%a");`. @localheinz's example is working correctly. It's 12 days btw. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/K2dt3)

Comment: yes. working now with both '%d' and '%a'. Other answer by @Alive to Die is also working. I don't know which one should I accept... :-(

Comment: Question has already been closed as duplicate, no worries!

Comment: Question may be duplicate, but problem is not. other solutions did not work for me :(

Comment: Thank you for the solution...

Comment: AFAIK you can still accept an answer after the question has been marked as duplicate. You should accept the answer that helped you the **most**.

Comment: I am sorry @localheinz, although your answer works perfectly and gives clearer picture, I am selecting Alive to Die 's answer because it was first.

Comment: No problem, @Ahsan!